# Google places API only autocompletes street name field . . . but throws no errors

Tags: django, django-forms, google-places-api

I'm new to Google's Places API. I'm trying to get a Django form to autocomplete, but for some reason, only one of the fields (Street 2) will autocomplete. The rest are just blank. And my console throws no errors, so I really have no idea what the issue is.

The other WEIRD thing . . . the inputs are holding the initial values that I passed to the form from the Django view even though the google autocomplete javascript has set them to "" before trying to autofill them. Is that normal?

Here's the HTML:

```
   <div id="locationField">
            <input id="autocomplete" name="search_address" onFocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Search for your address . . ." type="text" />
   </div>

   <hr class="hr-style">

   <div >
           <strong>Street</strong>
           <input id="street_name" name="street" type="text" value="1030 E State Street" />                
   </div>
   <div >
           <strong>Street 2</strong>
           <input id="route" name="street2" type="text" value="Apt. 2A" />                         
   </div>
   <div >
          <strong>City</strong>
          <input id="city" name="city" type="text" value="Los Angeles" />                           
   </div>
   <div class="6u 12u$(small) ">
          <strong>State</strong>
          <select id="state" name="state"> 
          <!-- options removed for brevity's sake -->              
   </div>
   <div class="6u 12u$(small) ">
          <strong>Zip</strong>
         <input id="zipcode" name="zipcode" type="text" value="90210" />

   </div>
```

And the javascript, just copied from Google and modified with my input id's:

```
//geosearch powered by Google

    // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
    // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

    // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

    $(function(){
        initAutocomplete();
    });

    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
      street_name: 'short_name',
      route: 'long_name',
      city: 'long_name',
      state: 'short_name',
      zipcode: 'short_name'
    };

    function initAutocomplete() {
      // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
      // location types.
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
          {types: ['geocode']});

      // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
      // fields in the form.
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    // [START region_fillform]
    function fillInAddress() {
      // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = "";
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
      }

      // Get each component of the address from the place details
      // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
          var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
          document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
      }
    }
    // [END region_fillform]

    // [START region_geolocation]
    // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
    // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
    function geolocate() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var geolocation = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: geolocation,
            radius: position.coords.accuracy
          });
          autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
      }
    }
    // [END region_geolocation
```

I'm thinking it has got to be failing somehow at this if statement in `fillinAddress()`, but I can't tell why:

```
if (componentForm[addressType]) {
              var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
              document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
```

Any help would be appreciated! And here's a screenshot of the form!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try `console.log(place.address_components[i]);` in that for-loop to see if the contents match what you're expecting.

Comment: @spiv THANK YOU! That led me to the problem. I'm adding an answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can NOT rename the address form components. (I had renamed '`locality`' to be '`city`' and '`administrative_area_level_1`' to be '`state`.') I'm so new to this; I had no idea! I just thought that the variable names in the javascript had to match your input id's in your HTML. Turns out the address form components have to stay:

```
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
```